# Iterating over an NSOrderedSet

Tags: swift, nsorderedset

I'm trying to iterate over an instance of NSOrderedSet. Something like this:

```
func myFunc() {
    var orderedSet = NSOrderedSet(array: [ 42, 43, 44])

    for n in orderedSet {
        NSLog("%i", n)
    }
}
```

...however the for loop line produces this compiler error:

```
'NSOrderedSet' does not have a member named 'Generator'
```

Now I could convert it to an array like this:

```
    for n in orderedSet.array {
        NSLog("%i", n)
    }
```

...but I wondered if there was a better solution?

I'm also keen to understand why it's possible to iterate over a set but not an ordered set? `NSOrderedSet` implements `NSFastEnumeration`, so it should work right?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can iterate over an ordered set with

```
let orderedSet = NSOrderedSet(array: [ 42, 43, 44])
orderedSet.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (elem, idx, stop) -> Void in
    println("\(idx): \(elem)")
}
```

**UPDATE:** As of Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3), `NSOrderedSet` conforms to
`SequenceType` and can be enumerated with `for ... in ...`:

```
let orderedSet = NSOrderedSet(array: [ 42, 43, 44])
for elem in orderedSet {
    println(elem)
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - I love Stackoverflow; ask a naive question and get two helpful posts within minutes, one of which provides an all-round-better solution to the problem. Accepting this answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The Swifty, simplest, and most general solution would be to shallow copy to an array in O(1) - per the docs.  This would allow you to use Swift's other functional techniques and functions.

```
import Swift
import Foundation


println("Simplest, most accessible, O(1) performance: shallow copy to array:")

var set = NSOrderedSet(array: map(0...7) { d in d })
for d in set.array as [Int] {
    print("\t\(d)")
}

println("\n\nIn general - for other types and cases, you could create a sequence:")

extension NSOrderedSet {
    func sequenceOf<T>(t:T.Type) -> SequenceOf<T> {
        var current = 0
        return SequenceOf(GeneratorOf({ () -> T? in
            return current < self.count ? self.objectAtIndex(current++) as? T : nil
        }))
    }
}

for d in set.sequenceOf(Int.self) {
    print("\t\(d)")
}
```

Simplest, most accessible, O(1) performance: shallow copy to array:

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7

In general - for other types and cases, you could create a sequence:

0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7

Answer (score 2):

`NSOrderedSet` doesn't conform to `SequenceType`. `NSOrderedSet` is subclass of `NSObject` and not `NSSet` as one could imagine. I guess Apple engineers overlooked it.

Comment: Yes, it would make sense that NSOrderedSet implements SequenceType, +1.