# Swift NSOrderedSet Iterating Over to access Attributes - CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nsorderedset

In Core Data I have made 2 entities -- a) WeatherResponse which has 'location' as an attribute and b) Forecast which has 'Day', 'Temperature' and 'Condition' as the attributes. Below is the 'one to many' relationship.

[image]

The classes are below:

```
class CDWeatherResp: NSManagedObject {
@NSManaged var cdLocation: String?
@NSManaged var locForecast: NSOrderedSet?
}

class CDForecast: NSManagedObject {
@NSManaged var day: String?
@NSManaged var temperature: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var conditions: String?
@NSManaged var forecastLocation: NSManagedObject?
}
```

I have managed to save some data as NSOrderedSet in:
**CDWeatherResp.locForecast** relationship. (This is working fine. Each index contains 1 forecast related info (i.e.: day, temperature & conditions)

**Question**: How do I access the attributes of the "CDForecast" class so that I can do something like 'CDWeatherResp.locForecast.day'

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603657/iterating-over-an-nsorderedset) but could not replicate it for the way I want

Comment: Do you want the day of one specific forecast or the days of all forecasts of this weatherresp? Or do you want to iterate over the forecasts?

Comment: I want to iterate over the forecasts...in each iteration I should be able to access the day attribute

Comment: You can iterate over the ordered set like in [Iterating over an NSOrderedSet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603657/iterating-over-an-nsorderedset) and [Swift NSSet & CoreData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091338/swift-nsset-coredata)

Comment: I have seen both posts before but unfortunately they did not work :(

Comment: We can't help you if you don't tell us what you did and why it isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had today similar issue and I solved it using this syntax:

```
for f in weatherResp.locForecast {
   let forecast = f as! CDForecast
   print(f.day)
}
```